# Download SQLite database from Internet and load into Android application

Tags: android, sqlite, download

For my android application, I would like to use a large database (about 45 MB).

One solution would be to include the (splitted) database in the assets folder and copy it to the database directory on the first startup.

But this would consume disk space twice - one time in the assets folder where the file can't be deleted and one time in the database directory where it has been copied to.

So I would rather like to download the database from the Internet (webserver) on the first startup. How could I do this? Can I download a complete SQLite file and save it to the database directory? Or should I rather go with JSON data files that are used to populate the database?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> One solution would be to include the (splitted) database in the assets folder and copy it to the database directory on the first startup.

It would not have to be split, just ZIPped. See [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for an example.

> How could I do this?

Use `HttpUrlConnection`. Or, use `HttpClient`.

> Can I download a complete SQLite file and save it to the database directory?

Yes. Use [`getDatabasePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to get the correct local path to use.

> Or should I rather go with JSON data files that are used to populate the database?

You could, but for 45MB, that would be ghastly slow.

Comment: Thank you! `SQLiteAssetHelper` looks interesting, but nevertheless, the maximum size of assets is 1MB, isn't it? So it doesn't matter if the file is zipped or not -  it's this limit. So would you recommend to use the `SQLiteAssetHelper` or the download from a webserver?

Comment: @MarcoW.: "the maximum size of assets is 1MB, isn't it?" -- AFAIK, that's the max size of an asset that gets compressed by `aapt`. You can have bigger assets that that, so long as `aapt` won't compress them, which is why `SQLiteAssetHelper` uses a ZIP file. Your arguments for downloading from a Web server are still very valid (e.g., duplicate space) -- I was merely clarifying your "splitted" reference, for anyone else encountering this question. BTW, you could also use `DownloadManager` to download the database, though you would then move it into final position yourself once downloaded.

Comment: @CommonsWare, would you mind provide an example of downloading a database file into sdcard then use `SQLiteAssetHelper` to copy and use it? Thank you

Comment: @blueware: `SQLiteAssetHelper` is for packaging a database in `assets/`. It is not for downloading a database file.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yep, that's correct but If you would help with this, I will appreciate that. As for the `SQLiteAssetHelper ` I compressed a database(9MB), its size down to (3MB)  -> put in `Assets` but app size increased by (9MB) not by (3MB), any idea?

Comment: @blueware: Sorry, I do not have an example of downloading a SQLite database.

Answer (score 9):

Having been asked what solution I ended up with, here's the code I used (roughly). It may not be complete anymore, and it's not elegant or clean, either. But maybe it can be of help to you.

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String SD_CARD_FOLDER = "MyApp";
    private static final String DB_DOWNLOAD_PATH = "http://www.example.org/downloads/dictionary.sqlite";
    private Database mDB = null;
    private DatabaseDownloadTask mDatabaseDownloadTask = null;
    private DatabaseOpenTask mDatabaseOpenTask = null;

    private class DatabaseDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.please_wait));
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.downloading_database));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
            try {
                File dbDownloadPath = new File(Database.getDatabaseFolder());
                if (!dbDownloadPath.exists()) {
                    dbDownloadPath.mkdirs();
                }
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(DB_DOWNLOAD_PATH);
                InputStream content = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    if (execute.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) { return null; }
                    content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                    long downloadSize = execute.getEntity().getContentLength();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Database.getDatabaseFolder()+Database.DATABASE_NAME+".sqlite");
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    int read;
                    long downloadedAlready = 0;
                    while ((read = content.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        downloadedAlready += read;
                        publishProgress((int) (downloadedAlready*100/downloadSize));
                    }
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                    content.close();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    if (content != null) {
                        try {
                            content.close();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e1) {}
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog = null;
            }
            if (result.equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, getString(R.string.database_download_success), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mDatabaseOpenTask = new DatabaseOpenTask();
                mDatabaseOpenTask.execute(new Context[] { MyActivity.this });
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.database_download_fail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }

    }

    private class DatabaseOpenTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Database> {

        @Override
        protected Database doInBackground(Context ... ctx) {
            try {
                String externalBaseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                // DELETE OLD DATABASE ANFANG
                File oldFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+SD_CARD_FOLDER);
                File oldFile = new File(oldFolder, "dictionary.sqlite");
                if (oldFile.exists()) {
                    oldFile.delete();
                }
                if (oldFolder.exists()) {
                    oldFolder.delete();
                }
                // DELETE OLD DATABASE ENDE
                File newDB = new File(Database.getDatabaseFolder()+"dictionary.sqlite");
                if (newDB.exists()) {
                    return new Database(ctx[0]);
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.please_wait), "Loading the database! This may take some time ...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Database newDB) {
            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                mProgressDialog = null;
            }
            if (newDB == null) {
                mDB = null;
                AlertDialog.Builder downloadDatabase = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
                downloadDatabase.setTitle(getString(R.string.downloadDatabase));
                downloadDatabase.setCancelable(false);
                downloadDatabase.setMessage(getString(R.string.wantToDownloadDatabaseNow));
                downloadDatabase.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.download), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        mDatabaseDownloadTask = new DatabaseDownloadTask();
                        mDatabaseDownloadTask.execute();
                    }
                });
                downloadDatabase.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                downloadDatabase.show();
            }
            else {
                mDB = newDB;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mDatabaseDownloadTask != null) {
            if (mDatabaseDownloadTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                mDatabaseDownloadTask.cancel(true);
            }
        }
        if (mDatabaseOpenTask != null) {
            if (mDatabaseOpenTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                mDatabaseOpenTask.cancel(true);
            }
        }
        if (mProgressDialog != null) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            mProgressDialog = null;
        }
        if (mDB != null) {
            mDB.close();
            mDB = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.sd_card_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        mDatabaseOpenTask = new DatabaseOpenTask();
        mDatabaseOpenTask.execute(new Context[] { this });
    }

}
```

**Database.java**

public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
private String DATABASE_PATH = null;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.my.package";
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    DATABASE_PATH = getDatabaseFolder()+DATABASE_NAME+".sqlite";
    db = getWritableDatabase();
}

public static String getDatabaseFolder() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/data/"+PACKAGE_NAME+"/databases/";
}

@Override
public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    try {
        if (db != null) {
            if (db.isOpen()) {
                return db;
            }
        }
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
     if (db != null) {
         db.close();
         db = null;
     }
     super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { }
```

}

Comment: Any special reason for renaming the db? File tempFile = new File(Database.getDatabaseFolder()+"temp.sqlite");
                    tempFile.renameTo(new File(Database.getDatabaseFolder()+"dictionary.sqlite"));

Comment: @LomaRoma You're right, this is superfluous now. However, if you don't rename the file, you have to change the name when writing the database file to disk. I've edited the answer. Please note that there are several other pieces in that snippet that may be improved or are even superfluous.

Comment: I'm having problems with downloading an sqlite db and using it in the app.. Basically, the SQLite throws an error that the db is corrupted, which is not the case. When i think about it, it looks like that corruption error is thrown when the db is changed without being opened (for example delete old db file + download new one) Could that be it? Did you have these problems?

Answer (score 3):

I think the JSON approach would be a better idea if your database is that large.

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe that when you release an update to your application, your device will download the entire application.  If you're bundling a 45mb file with your application that would mean that every time you push an update, your users are going to be stuck with downloading a 45mb file.  Not a good idea.

What you could do is include the properly structured database with no data in your application.  When the user opens the application it could connect to your web server and get the JSON data to populate the database.  This way when the user updates your application they won't get stuck with downloading a new large file.  Updates do not wipe out existing databases.

You could even fancy things up and get parts of the database through JSON until the user has everything.  This way if you're doing a monster query and they lose connection to the internet nothing too bad will happen.

Comment: Thanks you! The aspect of updates that should not include the large database file everytime is important, for sure. So I should definitely go with a small application that downloads all necessary data on the first run. But as Commonsware suggests, JSON seems to be slower than just downloading the complete SQLite database file.