# How to connect amazon s3 bucket database(sqlite3) using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, mysqli, sqlite

How to connect sqlite3 database from Amazon S3 Bucket using codeigniter?

I am using codeigniter, with multiple databases like mysql, sqlite3. But i don't know how to connect Amazon S3 Bucket database(sqlite3) using codeigniter.

I except to connect sqlite3 database from Amazon S3 Bucket.

Comment: I believe that amazon does not have a SQLite service since this is based on a file and not an SQL server, that works only as backup, too slow for real time service.

Comment: I was going to point the performance issue as well. Object storage is not the appropriate way to run a database as it is too slow as the whole object needs to be read or written even if you need to read or change a single byte). It may not be very noticeable at first, but as the database grows, it'll become unusable

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5+, the php_sqlite extension is enabled by default. In Linux or Unix operating systems, you must build SQLite as a shared extension, although most pre-built packages are already configured correctly.

You only need to define two things in **system/application/config/database.php**, the database filename and the database driver:

```
    $db['default']['database'] = "./system/database/sqlite/blog.sdb";
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = "sqlite";
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Right, but my database is in amazon s3 bucket, then which url i can used?

Comment: I don't think you can use SQLite Database from a remote server. It needs to be a file on the server. [Refrence 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42583242/2174728)